# Integral over $[0,1]$ of $g\left(x^{1/(2n+1)}\right)$ vanishes

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and such that

$$\int_0^1 g\left(x^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}\right)\,dx = 0, \quad n=0, 1, 2, \dots$$

Show that $g \equiv 0$ on $[0,1]$.

---

My idea was to use Stone-Weierstrass but not sure exactly how to go about that.

Comment: Set $y=x^{1\over 2n+1}, x=y^{2n+1}$ your hypothesis is $\int _0^1g(y)y^{2n}d y=0$...Then you can conclude

Comment: @Thomas is the idea to use an even polynomial to approximate $g$ (we can do this since we can simply extended $g:[0,1]$ to $g:[-1,1]$ and making it even in the obvious way) and then end up with $\int_{-1}^1 g^2 = 0$?

Comment: or use Stone Weierstrass, as you wish..